# How do you type Unicode characters using hexadecimal codes on an Android phone?

Tags: browser

The title says it all. I want to be able to type special characters from all over the unicode range into web pages, but don't know how to. Is there an app or plugin or whatever that allows me to bring up an option while in Firefox or Chrome on my Android phone?

Comment: There might be a keyboard with that functionality. I have tried many keyboards but can't remember ever seeing that though :(

Answer (score 0):

I was just now interested in the same thing. I couldn't find any keyboard app that lets you do that "in-place" – in the overlay, without leaving the app you are typing in.

But otherwise, the app [UnicodePad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.hotmist.unicodepad) lets you do just that: entering hex if you know it. There's also a lookup table, search and everything.